# Selenium button click not working using button.click()

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, selenium-chromedriver

i was trying to load a page and press button, but it seems that i am doing something wrong.
I used to know to these things but new selenium update made things more hard now.

here is the code.

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By



browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe")

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("https://quizlet.com/217866991/match")

time.sleep(5)


button = browser.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"UIButton UIButton--hero")

# Click the button
button.click()
```

I tried many times to find solution but things did not work.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues here:

1. You need use `WebDriverWait` `expected_conditions` instead of hardcoded delay.
2. `UIButton` `UIButton--hero` are **multiple** class name values. To use them you need to use CSS_SELECTOR or XPATH, not CLASS_NAME since CLASS_NAME receives **single** value.

The following code works:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")

webdriver_service = Service('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, service=webdriver_service)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

url = "https://quizlet.com/217866991/match/"
driver.get(url)

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".UIButton.UIButton--hero"))).click()
```

The result screen is

[image]